# Why am I limited to only one MIDI CC parameter at a buffer size of 128 samples?

Tags: midi, daw, audio-interfaces

My set up is RME HDSP 9652 MIDI out to MIDI Solutions powered splitter, which feeds a synths MIDI on channel 1. Now I've noticed that when I set my DAW's buffer size to 128 samples, I can only control on MIDI CC parameter. Anymore than 1 CC parameter over that channel either get wonky, or don't respond at all. If I go up to 256 samples, everything I have the ability to send as many CC parameters as I wish. Why is this? Could the splitter be limiting the amount of parameters I can send, or is it an audio interface limitation?

Comment: The splitter does not know about the audio buffer size; this must be an RME driver problem.

Comment: have you tried to reinstall the drivers?

Comment: @jonhatansmith I have not.

Comment: well perhaps you should :)

Comment: Haha. I will this weekend (as I have been planning), a time when I can do this plus I will check to see if the RME needs a firmware upgrade or not. I suspect it does because the manual does not correspond to the software options.